# FCM and Swift firebase-sdk version 8.1.0 localization problem

Tags: swift, firebase, sdk, localization, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm hoping to get some answers here, I have been searching and try almost everything. I even tried to customized my firebase sdk to fit to localization format but it doesnt work. the Push notification on my iphone shows: REMINDER_TO_BRUSH_YOUR_TEETH instead of the localization text i have on my app.

What i tried is:

```
"notification": {
    "title": "CompanyTitle",
    "body": "REMINDER_TO_BRUSH_YOUR_TEETH"
    "body_loc_key": "REMINDER_TO_BRUSH_YOUR_TEETH" <----- Also tried to add that here
  },
  "androidConfig": {
    "priority": "high",
    "ttl": "120s",
    "notification": {
      "color": "#FFFF00",
      "sound": "default"
    }
  },
  "apnsConfig": {
    "payload": {
      "aps": {
        "badge": 17,
        "body_loc_key": "REMINDER_TO_BRUSH_YOUR_TEETH" <----- Added that
      }
    }
  },
  "token": "cwCqkaNhrE_GsNzrNXxn7V:APA91bHNLg0F7ho9tvOqosWopX9L28FnZxHNoiwxvWJDekVt9hX2RgNa6W_CNUaRe22J2iKcMc5waGHOiC57fLF1H4c-yqOtN7eTujYGWwdMAoGHJEM828-mIa1sMCrSQbZwL7MZOKJI"
}
```

My piece of code:

```
private Message.Builder getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        AndroidConfig androidConfig = getAndroidConfig(request.getTopic());
        ApnsConfig apnsConfig = getApnsConfig(request.getTopic(), request.getBadge(), "REMINDER_TO_BRUSH_YOUR_TEETH");
        
        Notification notification = Notification
                .builder()
                .setTitle(request.getTitle())
                .setBody(request.getMessage())
                .build();
        
        return Message.builder()
                .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig).setAndroidConfig(androidConfig).setNotification(notification);
    }

 private ApnsConfig getApnsConfig(String topic, int badge, String locKey) {
        return ApnsConfig.builder()
                .setAps(Aps.builder().setBadge(badge).setLocKey(locKey).setCategory(topic).setThreadId(topic).build()).build();
    }
```

Thank you for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a syntax issue. Try the following:

```
"apnsConfig": {
    "payload": {
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "title": "some title",
                "body": "some body"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for pointing it out! That was the problem! Voted up!